# vibrator.cancel not called in OnDestroy of service class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, notifications

**AlarmService.kt**

```
class AlarmService : Service() {
private var vibrator: Vibrator? = null

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    vibrator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        val vibratorManager = this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
        vibratorManager.defaultVibrator
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    }
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): 
Int {
  val pattern = longArrayOf(1500, 800, 800, 800)
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            vibrator?.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(pattern, 0))
  } else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    vibrator?.vibrate(pattern, 0)
 }
}

 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    vibrator?.cancel() // ---< This is not called
    Log.e("served", "Service Stopped") // ---< This is called and shows in logcat
  }

}
```

In My **BroadcastRecciever**,

```
 private fun snoozeAlarm(context: Context?, intent: Intent?){
 val intentService = Intent(context.applicationContext, 
 AlarmService::class.java)
    context.applicationContext.stopService(intentService)

 }
```

As you can see, vibrator?.cancel() is not called when I tried to stop the service class from broadcastReciever.

The notification in my service is cleared but phone keeps vibrating.

Tested with emulator (pixel 2) api 31

**UPDATE**

It appears, this is only an issue with android studio emulator using bumblebee

When I ran with a real device, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the order of the operations in Your `onDestroy` method. Most importantly put the `super` call at the end of the method:

```kotlin
override fun onDestroy() {
    vibrator?.cancel()
    Log.e("served", "Service Stopped")
    
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Freeing up resources and uninitializing any child classes probably should be done on a fully functional object and since Your service was previously in the destruction process already (because of calling `super.onDestroy()` before your own operations) it *might have had* some impact on the `vibrator?.cancel()` code completion.

Comment: I've tried that. Sadly, it didn't work...

Comment: It appears it's an issue with the emulator, running with android studio bumblebee. When I ran with a real device, it worked.